# how to raise Google Big Query daily query quota

Tags: google-bigquery

We are running a batch process, and hitting the daily query quota of 20,000.

Is there a way to raise the limit?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The query-per-day limit (currently 40k / day) is one that we're generally happy to raise. In general, it is there to prevent abuse scenarios (people who use BigQuery as a calculator, as in `SELECT 17 + 32`).  If you're running real queries over non-trivial sized data, we will almost certainly be willing to raise this ceiling.

If you've got a contact with Google Cloud Support, please let them know your project ID.

If you do *not* have a support contact, you can indicate your project ID here, or e-mail me (tigani@google.com) and I will route the request appropriately.

Comment: Sent you an email with the project id earlier.  Please let me know when the limits can be raised and what the new limit (if any) is.  Also, is the concurrent quota also raised at the same time?  Thanks.